# Limiting distribution of $V_n=\sqrt{n}\cdot \text{min}{\{X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n}\}$ where $f_X(x) =\frac{2}{x^3}I_{(1,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> $X_1$, $X_2$, . . . are iid random variables having pdf
>
> $$f_X(x) =\frac{2}{x^3}I_{(1,\infty)}(x)$$
>
> Let
>
> $$V_n=\sqrt{n}\cdot \text{min}{\{X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n}\}$$
>
> Consider the sequence $V_1$, $V_2$, . . . and give the pmf or pdf of
>   the limiting distribution.

I first note that the cdf of $X$ is given by

$$ F_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
1-\frac{1}{x^2} & x \gt 1 \\
0 & x\leq 1 \\
\end{cases} $$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
F_{V_n}(v)
&=\mathsf P(V_n\leq v)\\\\
&=\mathsf P(\sqrt{n}\cdot \text{min}{\{X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n}\}\leq v)\\\\
&=\mathsf P\left(\text{min}{\{X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n}\}\leq \frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\\\
&=1-\mathsf P\left(X_1\gt \frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n\\\\
&=1-\left(1-\mathsf P\left(X_1 \leq \frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)^n\\\\
&=1-\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(\frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2}\right)\right)^n\\\\
&=1-\left(\frac{n}{v^2}\right)^n
\end{align*}$$

Altogether, we have

$$ F_{V_n}(t)=  
\begin{cases} 
1-\left(\frac{n}{v^2}\right)^n & v\gt \sqrt{n} \\
0 & v\leq \sqrt{n} \\
\end{cases} $$

and so for all $v\in\mathbb{R}$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_{V_n}(t)=1$$

Since there is not a valid cdf equal to $1$ except at points of discontinuity, a limiting distribution does not exist.

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: Sure about the text of the exercise? Since $X_i\geqslant1$ almost suerly, for every $i$, $V_n\geqslant\sqrt n$ almost surely, for every $n$, hence, with no computations, one knows that $V_n\to\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Some of the solutions don't have limiting distributions so this seems to be one of them. I'm just not sure what good notation would be for the cdf if I did include it.

Comment: (1) The notation $F_{V_n}(v)$ suddenly changed to $F_{T_n}(t)$. (2) For each fixed $v$, $v \leq \sqrt{n}$ holds for all sufficiently large $n$ and we know that this implies $F_{V_n}(v) = 0$. This also matches Did's comment that $V_n \geq \sqrt{n}$ almost surely. What is your rationale for concluding that the limit is $1$?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. So essentially, my thinking was we would expect the minimum to get infinitely close to $1$, and so $v\rightarrow\sqrt{n}$ and so $\frac{n}{v^2}\rightarrow 1$. Wasn't sure how to take the limit from there since we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1-\left(\frac{n}{v^2}\right)^n$. Here, it looks like we have convergence in probability inside a limit.

Comment: Why can we treat $v$ as fixed? Doesn't it depend on $n$?

Comment: The mode of limit you are interested is vague convergence, i.e., the pointwise convergence of $F_{V_n}$ (possibly except at countably many points), which amounts to analyze the limit $F_{V_n}(v)$ as $n\to\infty$ for each *given* $v$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But if $v$ is fixed, and $n$ gets large, why does that limit approach $0$ and not $-\infty$?

Comment: The expression $1-(n/v^2)^n$ diverges to $-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $v \neq 0$. But this is *not* your function $F_{V_n}(v)$. Your function $F_{V_n}(v)$ is defined piecewise according to whether $v > \sqrt{n}$ or $v \leq \sqrt{n}$, and you need to count this fact. And a quick sanity check: $F_{V_n}(v)$ always lies in $[0, 1]$, so it can never be negative.

Comment: So would the limiting distribution just not exist since there is not a valid cdf equal to $0$?

Comment: Yes, as Did pointed out in his/her comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$F_{T_n}(v)=  
\begin{cases} 
1-\left(\frac{n}{v^2}\right)^n & v\gt \sqrt{n}  \\
0 & v\leq \sqrt{n} \\
\end{cases}$

Logically speaking, the right way to understand $F_{T_n}$ is the following: $ \forall n, \ \exists v,  \ s.t. \ c v > \sqrt{n} \Rightarrow F_{T_n}(t) = 1-\left(\frac{n}{v^2}\right)^n $

For a fixed $n \ $, if the $v$ in your hands can't make the inequality hold: $\frac{n}{v^2} < 1$, then you just assign a $0$ to $F_{T_n}(v)$. In this way, $F_{T_n}$ never goes beyond $1$ because that's how you assign the probabilities (how you design this distribution)

Comment: I have edited my attempted solution.